# Closing button for add a logo doesn't work

Tags: bug, developer-story

In developer story's `story view` from `Add new item` section, some items have a `Click to add a logo` section, including a close button at the top right side.

I expect that close button to close the `Click to add a logo` section which it doesn't.

So I'm wondering if it's a bug or just something that I don't know about.